# What would be a good sub for pineapple, any other fruit or veggie for a strawberry pineapple mint salsa

Tags: substitutions, fruit, pineapple, salsa

I need to sub pineapple with something else, im highly allergic to it.

Comment: Use another tropical fruit such as mangoes, papaya or guava.

Comment: I'm not sure what would be best ... but pineapple has a fair bit of acidity / sourness to it, so you might want to add some lime juice or other citrus along with whatever you substitute

Comment: It might be easier to just look for a strawberry-mint-somethingelse-salsa, instead of trying to modify an unsuitable recipe

Answer (score 6):

Kiwi.

Don't knock it until you try it. It will have a similar acidity and texture to pineapple. Use ripe kiwi and maybe a touch extra lime juice!

Comment: A good idea.  They'd also release a lot of moisture when eating, much like a pineapple.

Comment: Plus, it's even more visually exciting and different - a total conversation starter.

Answer (score 2):

Your pineapple in a salsa is going to add some sweetness, a lot of acidity, and crisp chunks that will be important to the texture.

While other tropical fruits would be have the sweetness and interesting flavor, I can't think of anything that adds the acidity and texture. When ripe, mango and guava are quite soft and although there are delicious mango salsas it won't be similar to the pineapple at all.

You also need a fruit that will not be too distinctive of a flavor because that might distract from the strawberry or clash with the mint.

I think that I would use meyer lemons.
The meyers would be sweet enough not to bash you in the face but they still have some of the tartness. The texture pops kind of like a pineapple and the flavor compliments both strawberry and mint.

Answer (score 2):

Mango, specifically green mango. You'll get a similar texture, some tartness, and it is already a widely used thing in salsas. You could easily pick how tart you want it by switching to s slightly riper Mango.

https://www.google.com/search?q=green+mango+strawberry+salsa&oq=green+mango+strawberry+salsa&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.4770j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

I'd lean towards mango, with some lime juice to help match the acidity.

Answer (score 1):

other possibilities to substitute for pineapple in that salsa:
1) fresh rhubarb 1/4" cubed, some extra rhubarb juice, and sugar
2) jicima cubed and gently steamed, tamarind paste, and lime juice
3) big blueberries, halved, and sugar 
4) tart green apples cubed plus sugar and a little apple cider vinegar